# How does one pass a class through an array and then fill the array with a txt document

Tags: java

So... My goal here to run this class through an array then fill the array with a .txt document with 43 instances which I will then take user data and compare the two to find an ideal match. I should note that this is for a seating plan - 
The text document looks like so -

01 STANDARD True False True F False

```
public class Seat {

    private  String eMail = "";
    private int number;
    private String type;
    private boolean window;
    private boolean aisle;
    private boolean table;
    private String f;
    private String b;
    private boolean ease;

    public Seat(int number, String type, boolean window, boolean aisle, boolean table, String f, String b, boolean ease) {
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.window = window;
        this.aisle = aisle;
        this.table = table;
        this.f = f;
        this.b = b;
        this.ease = ease;
    }
    public String geteMail() {
        return eMail;
    }
    public void seteMail(String eMail) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public boolean isWindow() {
        return window;
    }
    public void setWindow(boolean window) {
        this.window = window;
    }
    public boolean isAisle() {
        return aisle;
    }
    public void setAisle(boolean aisle) {
        this.aisle = aisle;
    }

    public boolean isTable() {
        return table;
    }
    public void setTable(boolean table) {
        this.table = table;
    }
    public String getF() {
        return f;
    }
    public void setF(String f) {
        this.f = f;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public boolean isEase() {
        return ease;
    }
    public void setEase(boolean ease) {
        this.ease = ease;
    }
}

public class Driver {
    static Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("//Users//Mike//Desktop//Seats-2.txt"));

        String reservation = inFile.nextLine();
        Seat seat [] = new Seat [43];


        //while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
            //for(int i = 0; i <= reservation.length(); i++){
                //System.out.println(reservation.toString(seat));
            //}
        //}
```

I've tried methods such as equals(reservation.toString()) how ever these won't work due to the array being built from the Class Seat.
Any guidance will be very helpful.

I'm not looking for easy fix, just some guidance on where to look.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text file is small, let's just read it whole in a String

```
public static String ReadWholeFile(String filename) throws IOException
{
    final File file = new File(filename);
    final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    final byte[] data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    fis.read(data);
    fis.close();
    return new String(data, "UTF-8");
}
```

And then parse line by line, converting in Seats

```
public List<Seat> getSeats(String filename) throws IOException {
    final String[] lines = ReadWholeFile(filename).split("\n");

    final List<Seat> ret = new ArrayList<Seat>();

    for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++) 
        try {
            final String[] parts = lines[i].split("\\s"); // split on whitespaces
            final int num = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);

            ret.add(new Seat(num, parts[1], isTrue(parts[2]), isTrue(parts[3]), isTrue(parts[4]), isTrue(parts[5]), isTrue(parts[6]));
        }
        catch (Exception e) { /* whatever */ }

    return ret;
}
```

Strings that mean true are "T", "true", ...? If that's the case:

```
public static isTrue(String x) {
    return x.startsWith("T") || x.startsWith("t");
}
```

if you really don't want to read the whole file, you could go with:

```
public static List<Seat> getSeats2(String filename) {

    final List<Seat> ret = new ArrayList<Seat>();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        String line;
        while (line = br.readLine()) {
            final String[] parts = line.split("\\s"); // split on whitespaces
            // as above
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { /* handle errors */ }
    finally {
        if (br != null)
            try { br.close(); }
            catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: The .txt document is 43 lines long.
Either answer is perfect providing I can compare user data to each of the 6 sections of a line.
Thank you very much!

Comment: If I were to go with the second option how would I go about comparing user input to the information that's split... for example System.out.println("First or Standard class") string class = S.nextLine();

How would I then compare class the second part of array parts? :S
Thank you

Comment: @M.Abbott94 if (parts[1].equals("STANDARD")) type="standard"; else type="first";

Comment: String line;
        while (line = br.readLine()) {
            final String[] parts = line.split("\\s");

Comment: String line;
        while (line = br.readLine()) {
            final String[] parts = line.split("\\s");
Having some issues with the code above, it's saying theres a type mismatch because it cannot convert a boolean to string

Comment: Any suggestions? :/ 
Thank you

Comment: @M.Abbott94 Seat constructor says that arguments 6 and 7 are string, thus ret.add(new Seat(num, parts[1], isTrue(parts[2]), isTrue(parts[3]), isTrue(parts[4]), parts[5], parts[6], true /* i don't know what the last one is */));